# cinnamon panel icons oversized

Tags: icons, cinnamon

the panel icon size is too large on cinnamon in my ubuntu 14.04 as you can see in the lower right corner. how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a different icon theme?

Comment: ya tried the mac os theme....it works fine there. I wonder why its creating a problem when using win 7/8 icon theme

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in the latest Cinnamon versions.

You can upgrade Cinnamon using a PPA like **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly`**

Install the cinnamon with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

and then the issue should be fixed...

Oh and BTW: The icon pack is actually missing in that screenshot, if you want a Windows 7 icon pack, add **`ppa:noobslab/themes`** and **`ppa:noobslab/icons`** to your Software Sources using the method above. Then use the following commands to install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mindows-transformation-themes
sudo apt-get install win-icons
```

Now you should be able to get an icon pack.

**Update:**

Do **NOT** forget to purge the previous cinnamon configuration(s) with **`sudo apt-get purge cinnamon`** before you try to install Cinnamon under the new PPA.

Comment: +1 for this, this is a really good answer, take this as an example and compare it to the 10 answers you spammed in the last hour, one or two answers like this will earn more rep than spamming the main page with answers that don't answer questions. Shame this is on such an old question :)

Answer (score 0):

First purge the PPA and whatever you installed for your old cinnamon. Then use this command to add this letscape PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
```

Use this to install cinnamon and some beautiful extras:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon mint-themes
```

This works perfect for me, Hope to work for you.